# Error starting hyperledger-composer network after Fabric and Composer version upgrade

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I've come across an error starting the hyperledger-composer network that isn't answered in the composer-wiki.

```
✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers. 
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: transaction returned with failure: can't find PEM header: undefined 
Command failed
```

Checking pre-requisites,

- Fabric 1.2
- Composer 0.20.4
- Node 8.12.0
- Docker 18.01.1
- "composer network install" was successful, with file appearing in the docker peer at /var/hyperleder/production/chaincodes

After running the "composer network start" command, a "docker ps" shows new docker instance with name:

```
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-<<business-network-name>>-0.0.7
```

But any attempt to ping this results in a failure like this:

```
Error: Error trying to ping. Error: make sure the chaincode <<business-network-name>> has been successfully instantiated and try again: getccdata composerchannel/<<business-network-name>> responded with error: could not find chaincode with name '<<business-network-name>>'
```

Checking the log of the dev-peer0, it ends with the following:

```
2018-11-05T05:03:18.227Z [4264161f] ERROR    :Composer                 :Init()                    can't find PEM header: undefined
2018-11-05T05:03:18.227Z [4264161f] VERBOSE  :Composer                 :@PERF Init()              Total (ms) duration for txnID [4264161fc30a61c70884d4c7efb460fea6a755d07bc4852875c393346795227a]: 929.00
2018-11-05T05:03:18.228Z ERROR [lib/handler.js] [composerchannel-4264161f]Calling chaincode Init() returned error response [can't find PEM header: undefined]. Sending ERROR message back to peer
```

The corresponding error in the peer0 log is a big larger:

```
2018-11-05 05:03:18.229 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 439d [composerchannel][4264161f] failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" , error: transaction returned with failure: can't find PEM header: undefined
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).Execute
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:202
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*SupportImpl).Execute
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/support.go:131
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).callChaincode
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:173
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).SimulateProposal
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:287
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).ProcessProposal
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:501
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter.(*expirationCheckFilter).ProcessProposal
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter/expiration.go:61
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter.(*filter).ProcessProposal
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter/filter.go:31
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer._Endorser_ProcessProposal_Handler
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer/peer.pb.go:112
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:923
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:1148
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.1
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:637
runtime.goexit
    /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2361
2018-11-05 05:03:18.229 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> DEBU 439e [composerchannel][4264161f] Exit
```

Since this last worked I have updated composer from 0.19 to 0.20.4, and taken Fabric from 1.1 to 1.2.

Googling suggests that this kind of error "can't find PEM header: undefined" is associated with a change in key signing.  After tearing down Fabric I re-ran ./createPeerAdminCard.sh - is there another card or similar that needs to be re-created to accomodate the latest versions?

Comment: Are there any errors in the log of the dev-peer0... docker container?  Similarly are there errors in the peer0.org1... container?  It looks like you are starting v0.0.7 of your network - did v0.0.6 start OK? - if so what changes have you made between the versions?

Comment: I have not seen that error, but if you suspect the card, then I would delete the existing cards using `composer card delete` then make sure the environment variable FABRIC_VERSION is set to hlfv12 - then run the createPeerAdminCard script again.

Comment: one other comment, you should be using Fabric 1.2.1 specifically with Composer 0.20.4 (maybe that's what you meant, instead of 1.2 Fabric FYI)

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony thanks for the pointer, but I can't see 1.2.1 listed on the Fabric release page: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric#releases.   Can you confirm?

Comment: Thanks @RThatcher - you nailed it, see answer below.

Comment: @CapnSparrow - its there alright -> https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/tag/v1.2.1

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony apologies, you're quite right - I was only looking at the front page text and in true lazy dev style didn't drill down because it was midnight.   Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the the last remark from @Capn Sparrow

"the -A and -S parameters of the composer network start command HAD to be set to admin and adminpw respectively."

This is the correct and expected behaviour :-)

with the `composer network start` command the -A and -S are specifying an **existing user** in the CA that we want a new set of Credentials (certificate and keys) for which is then bound to a Composer System participant.

When you use the 'standard development fabric' this has a CA configured with a user called 'admin' with a secret of 'adminpw'.  If you had build your own Fabric from scratch you could choose the name and secret of your first default user.  Alternatively you could work with the fabric-ca client software to create additional users in the CA.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @R Thatcher for putting me onto the right direction.  This was all down to mismatching cards, and was resolved by clearing out everything and starting again.

Specifically, in /fabric-dev-servers:

```
./stopFabric.sh 
./teardownFabric.sh
composer card list
composer card delete -c admin@<business-network-name>
composer card delete -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1
./startFabric.sh
./createPeerAdminCard.sh
```

Then changing into the composer/business-network-name directory:

```
composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile business-network-name\@0.0.7.bna 
composer network start -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -n business-network-name -V 0.0.7 -A admin -S adminpw --file networkadmin.card
composer card import --file networkadmin.card --card admin@business-network-name
composer network ping -c admin@business-network-name
```

So yes, it was about mismatching cards and not cleaning these up as part of a new deployment.

Although not part of the original problem, it's also worth noting that the -A and -S parameters of the composer network start command HAD to be set to admin and adminpw respectively.  See composer issue [#3781](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3781).